# How to run angular 1.4 application if I installed angular 6

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm

I installed angular 6 with cli, however, my project is written on angular 1.4.
How to run it?

Comment: @cgTag, there is no point being rude to someone seeking help, even if they asked a totally wrong question. Politeness goes a long way imo.

Comment: AngularJS apps don't need or use Ahead-Of-Time compilation. Simply serve their pages.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to. Angular 2+ is not compatible with angular 1.x.

At most you might be able to get the folder structure such that `ng serve` will start the web server for you (and likely not even that depending on what it checks for); but it would be far simpler and faster to get something simple set up with Express.

Alternatively, if you have a C#/.NET backend just serving up the AngularJS files via `wwwroot` is the route to go here (and also works for Angular 2).

The angular CLI is worthless until you update to the new version(s) of Angular.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it easier for me to use IIS suppose I am running C# as server language?

Comment: @TuviaKhusid Certainly; probably should have specified that in the question :)

Comment: @BradlleyDotNet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706644/how-to-host-single-page-application-on-the-local-server-and-backend-on-remote-se